# Cloning SSD without mSATA-USB link?

Tags: ssd, clone

I'm upgrading the SSD on my Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro.

I'd like to clone the older, smaller SSD on the new one. Does this necessarily require some specific piece of hardware to link from the new SSD (mSata) to the notebook via USB? Is there an alternative, for example using an external USB hard drive as an intermediary?

Comment: Use a cloning software that works directly from a bootable cd, clone to intermediate usb hdd, mount the new msata, clone back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Clone using disk files to an intermediary if you'd like, then clone from those disk files to your new SSD.

I've done the same procedure myself when I only had a USB Mini cable. First I cloned the SSD to the external HDD, then replaced the SSD with the new one and cloned the contents back to the new drive.

As long as your new drive has a higher capacity than the older SSD, this should be smooth sailing.